# How to escape a " " in velocity

Tags: velocity

So my velocity is working fine if user sends **'lorem'** just fine, it also works great if he sends **lorem** but when he sends **"lorem"** it breaks,
is there any way that I can escape both " from that result that user is sending or even better to replace it with single quotes ? ( ' )

Comment: Try this :https://velocity.apache.org/tools/2.0/apidocs/org/apache/velocity/tools/generic/EscapeTool.html

Comment: I will look into it thank you so much mate !